# Is there any way to see which lines of JavaScript code were executed?

Tags: javascript

I have a function in JavaScript that is based on a few numbers and yes/no questions inputted into html forms, and then an answer is returned with subtle differences based on the input.

Is there any way to see or highlight which lines of code were executed to make sure the function use the correct "path"? Sometime like an app in VS code or somewhere else? I do not want to put an extra line of code every few lines to figure it out.

Comment: You could step debug it using `debugger` keyword

Comment: Sure is, like @ITgoldman mentions use your browser debugger,  you can stop / pause / step every instruction, add watches, modern Browsers have some very good debugging tools, even if you write your code in Typescript etc, (just make sure your in development mode when doing your builds).    And yes, you can even do this directly VS code too, very handy for debugging Node.js apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Code Coverage](https://v8.dev/blog/javascript-code-coverage) tool for this.

To show the Coverage tab in Chrome Developer Tools, open the console and type <kbd>Ctl-Shift-P</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd-Shift-P</kbd> on Mac) to get the command menu, then start typing `coverage` into the search field that pops up. Then you'll be able to click on `Show Coverage` command.

Comment: I don't see anything that goes through lines of code.  Just a URL with how many bytes.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but the documentation shows that the lines that are executed are marked in green, the lines that aren't executed are in red. There's nothing about bytes there.